# Adding element in array

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse

I have an array of Strings and I want to add a value on it. and also the array is only good for 5 values. and should be in a FIFO. how can I do that? here's my code:

```
private void openChart(){
    int[] x = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    int[] Addition = {};
```

I just only want to add a value on the Addition variable. how should I do that?

**UPDATE**:

I have a progress chart which actually show the game progress of the player. it displays the time of the player to finish the game.

`score` is the variable that holds the time and I want to add it on my `array`

Comment: Use `List<T>` or `Set<T>`.

Comment: can you show me how?

Comment: @user3698267 There are many good tutorials online about `List`. I suggest that you google for them.

Comment: I suggest you to use `ArrayList<>` or `List<>` it can add values at run time...

Comment: Sir @ZubairAhmadKhan can you show me how its done? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
         int[] Addition= {};
         Addition[0]=1;
         Addition[1]=2;
         Addition[2]=3;
         Addition[3]=4;
         Addition[4]=5;
```

Or

```
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)  // or you can use for(int i=0;x.length;i++) 
        {
          Addition[i]=i+1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Assume, that you save the time in a variable named "`score`", which I assume will be a string value, You can add it to your array as:

```
 String myStringArray = new String[5]; // Since You say, number 5 is fixed.

 String score = "10:20 AM";
 myStringArray[0] = score;

 score = "10:30 AM";
 myStringArray[1] = score;
```

and so on.... Hope this helps.. P

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

```
  int[] x = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
  int[] Addition = new int [x.length];

  int prevValue = 0;
  for (int i=0; i< x.length ; i++)
  {
       Addition[i]=prevValue + x[i];
       System.out.println(Addition[i] + "=" + prevValue + "+" + x[i]);
       prevValue = Addition[i];
  }
```

Your output will be:

```
1=0+1
3=1+2
6=3+3
10=6+4
15=10+5
```

Comment: @user3698267: Please see my answer update. Please comment if you need modifications or clarifications. Hope it helps :)

Comment: sir is there an easy way to add the score in the array of 5? and also to have a FIFO

Comment: Please tell me how the score value would be... Do you mean to say, you always want the latest 5 scores??

Comment: score is converted in seconds. and yes sir it should be the latest 5 scores. and also is it possible to use sharedpreference for this one?